# Visual Studio - ASP Website - Local IIS - Can the workspace name be included in the project URL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web, workspace

A bit of background, I'm using the following tools/environment:

- Visual Studio 2012
- TFS 2010
- Windows Server 2008 R2

I'm trying to get around the problem of using project URLs mapped to the local IIS for websites when using more than one workspace.

Example:
Website1 in Workspace1 is set to use the Local IIS Web Server with address:

`http://localhost/Website1`

If I open this website/project in Workspace2 I get an error telling me that:

`http://localhost/Website1 cannot be used because it already exists`

Is it possible to add a reference to the workspace name (without necessarily knowing it) to the project URL, something like `http://localhost/{WORKSPACE_NAME}/Website1`. This means that if I open the website in Workspace1 it will be mapped to `http://localhost/Workspace1/Website1` and if I open it in Workspace2 it will be mapped to `http://localhost/Workspace2/Website1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but...

If you uncheck "Apply server settings to all users(store in project file)" on the properties page on the "Web" tab,
it will create a .user file and keep that in the workspace so that you can have different Project Urls for each workspace.

I tried to find a way to include the workspace name in the Project URL but no luck.  This is slightly less magical but it works.

Comment: Thanks sm14, this is the solution we ended up going with